# AJAX call breaks .droppy() navbar expansion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have ran into an issue with jquery.droppy() and AJAX.

I have an HTML menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a id="toplev" href="/viewpage/69">Level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/viewpage/138">Level 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/149">Level 3-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/150">Level 3-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/148">Level 3-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/139">Level 3-4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>                             
  </li>
</ul>
```

I call the droppy function in my scripts.js file thusly:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav').droppy();
});
```

And All is good

I run an ajax call:

```
function reloadNavBar() {
    $.get('reloadnavbar',function(response) {
           document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = response; 
        }
    );
    $('#nav').droppy();
};
```

that updates the menu thusly:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a id="toplev" href="/viewpage/69">Level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/viewpage/138">Level 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/149">Level 3-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/150">Level 3-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/148">Level 3-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/139">Level 3-4</a></li>
          <li><a href="/viewpage/139">Level 3-5</a></li>  //This line added
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>                             
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now the menu does not expand like before the ajax call.  I CAN click the Level 1 link and it works, just does not expand the selection on hover.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the plugin after the AJAX call completes and the DOM is updated:

```
function reloadNavBar() {
    $.get('reloadnavbar', function(response) {
        $('#nav').html(response).droppy();
    });
};
```

Your current code attempts the reinitialisation *before* the AJAX has completed, as it was outside of the callback function.

Comment: Even though same answer as above, flagged as best answer due to code example

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your $.get function may not have returned prior to the html being updated, so your `$('#nav').droppy()` isn't executing against the newly generated content. Move it after the `document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = response` line, within the callback function.

Comment: That did the trick.  And I KNEW that too.  Sometimes I just cant see the forest for the trees